# Performance issue -  LRUMap() in AjaxStateHolder in JSF?

Tags: java, performance, jsf-1.2, ajax4jsf

I am using SUN JSF1.2 and Richfaces 3.3.1 in our application. As apart of performance tuning added the below parameters in the web.xml

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession</param-name>
   <param-value>2</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
   <param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews</param-name>
   <param-value>2</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Still when i inspected the session object i saw that org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxStateHolder was consuming almost 85%( Almost 10 MB) of the session memory. Even i tried to get the AjaxStateHolder object from session but not able to delete all the cached session.

I have searched the web, it was mentioned that is a problem exist in Richfaces.

Is there anyway to clear all those cached views from the LRMap.

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem similar to what's stated [here](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-3878):

I needed to make some custom modifications for IE9 and adding tooltips to the calendar component, so I grabbed the source and modified `protected static final int DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_VIEWS = 16;` to equal a value of 1.

I built the project using Maven 2.  Maven 3 will not work.

Changing all the places where that constant is declared fixed the problem for me.